# HTML/PHP to PDF? how....?

Tags: html, pdf

I have some page with tables and 1 img that I want to create a button to make it a pdf.
The problem is, it's hebrew (utf-8 encoded).
Is there any way to do it?
I tried to use jsPDF but it's dosen't support hebrew.

Basicly what I want to make is a button that will create a pdf file that I will send via email  as attachment.

Any suggestions?

Thank you!

This is what I've tried:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.2/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function demoFromHTML() {
        var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
        source = $('#content')[0];

        specialElementHandlers = {
            // element with id of "bypass" - jQuery style selector
            '#bypassme': function (element, renderer) {
                // true = "handled elsewhere, bypass text extraction"
                return true
            }
        };
        margins = {
            top: 80,
            bottom: 60,
            left: 40,
            width: 522
        };
        pdf.fromHTML(
            source, // HTML string or DOM elem ref.
            margins.left, // x coord
            margins.top, { // y coord
                'width': margins.width, // max width of content on PDF
                'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
            },
            function (dispose) {
                pdf.save('Test.pdf');
            }, margins
        );
    }
</script>

<a href="javascript:demoFromHTML()" class="button">Run Code</a>
<div id="content">
HTML HERE
</div>
```

Comment: [I think you can use RTL](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+PDF+rtl+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: You are looking to do HTML to PDF completely client side in the browser? Or server side? I recommend server side, as I am unaware of any good, general usage, HTML to PDF converter that is client side only. If client side only, why is that important?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use this fpdf tool it is very simple to use.
Here there is a demo of my code

```
if(isset($_POST['pdf'])){
    require('fpdf/fpdf.php');
    $sname = $_POST['sname'];
    $emailid = $_POST['emailid'];
    $joindate = $_POST['joindate'];
    $contact = $_POST['contact'];
    $birthdate = $_POST['birthdate'];
    $about = $_POST['about'];
    $today = date("Y");


    $pdf = new FPDF();
    $pdf -> AddPage();
    $pdf->Image('logo.png',85,6,40);
    // Line break
    $pdf->Ln(20);
    // Arial bold 15
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',15);
    // Move to the right
    $pdf->Cell(80);
    // Title
    $pdf->Cell(30,10,'Module '.$today,0,0,'C');
    $pdf->Ln(10);
    // Line break
    $pdf->Ln(20);

    $pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,0,1);
    $w = $pdf->GetStringWidth($contact)+60;
    $pdf->SetX((170-$w)/2);
    $pdf->Cell(40, 10, 'Name:', 0, 0, 'L');
    $pdf->Cell($w, 10, $sname, 0, 1, 'R');
    
    $pdf->Ln(10);

    $pdf->SetX((170-$w)/2);
    $pdf->Cell(40, 10, 'Birth Date:', 0, 0, 'L');
    $pdf->Cell($w, 10, $birthdate, 0, 1, 'R');

    $pdf->Ln(10);

    $pdf->SetX((170-$w)/2);
    $pdf->Cell(40, 10, 'Telephone:', 0, 0, 'L');
    $pdf->Cell($w, 10, $contact, 0, 1, 'R');

    $pdf->Ln(10);

    $pdf->SetX((170-$w)/2);
    $pdf->Cell(40, 10, 'Email:', 0, 0, 'L');
    $pdf->Cell($w, 10, $emailid, 0, 1, 'R');
    
    $pdf->Ln(10);

    $pdf->SetX((170-$w)/2);
    $pdf->Cell(40, 10, 'Date of Join:', 0, 0, 'L');
    $pdf->Cell($w, 10, $joindate, 0, 0, 'R');

    $pdf->Ln(30);
    
    $pdf->SetX((170-$w)/2);
    $pdf->Cell(40, 10, '', 0, 0, 'R');
    $pdf->Cell($w, 10, 'Signature:______________', 0, 0, 'R');
    
    $pdf->Output('I',"Module {$today} of {$sname}.pdf");
}
```

Comment: there is no any simple way of just taking some html page and convert it to pdf?
with fpdf i need to rewrite the whole tables...